# IONIC 2 templates

Tags: ionic2

Does anyone know where I can find all the available Ionic 2 startup templates? Currently I know ionic provides tutorial (seems a replacement to sidemenu in v1), tabs, blank as the default.

Is there any custom templates I can use with `ionic start [xx] tempName` ?

Update: currently (2/27/2017), ionic team added tutorial template back, and they also added a new template called super (login, signup included).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was looking too. Those you mentioned, it seems pretty much it. Sidemenu exists also for ionic 2, but I didn't managed to make it work so far.

I didn't find any others.

[Here is the link to all existing templates](https://github.com/ionic-team/)

Answer (score 55):

```
ionic start --list
```

gives:

```
blank ................ A blank starter project for Ionic
complex-list ......... A complex list starter template
maps ................. An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side menu
salesforce ........... A starter project for Ionic and Salesforce
sidemenu ............. A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navigation in the content area
tabs ................. A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface
```

**UPDATE: currently Ionic 3.7.0 gives more templates:**

```
ubuntu@x.x.x.x:~/prj$ ionic start --list
tabs ............... ionic-angular A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
blank .............. ionic-angular A blank starter project
sidemenu ........... ionic-angular A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
super .............. ionic-angular A starting project complete with pre-built pages, providers and best practices for Ionic development.
conference ......... ionic-angular A project that demonstrates a realworld application
tutorial ........... ionic-angular A tutorial based project that goes along with the Ionic documentation
aws ................ ionic-angular AWS Mobile Hub Starter
tabs ............... ionic1 A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface
blank .............. ionic1 A blank starter project for Ionic
sidemenu ........... ionic1 A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navigation in the content area
maps ............... ionic1 An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side menu
```

**Ionic 4 templates**

```
ionic start --list  

name     | project type  | description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
blank    | angular       | A blank starter project
sidemenu | angular       | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
tabs     | angular       | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
tabs     | ionic-angular | A starting project with a simple tabbed interface
blank    | ionic-angular | A blank starter project
sidemenu | ionic-angular | A starting project with a side menu with navigation in the content area
super    | ionic-angular | A starting project complete with pre-built pages, providers and best practices for Ionic development.
tutorial | ionic-angular | A tutorial based project that goes along with the Ionic documentation
aws      | ionic-angular | AWS Mobile Hub Starter
tabs     | ionic1        | A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface
blank    | ionic1        | A blank starter project for Ionic
sidemenu | ionic1        | A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navigation in the content area
maps     | ionic1        | An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side menu
```

Comment: This is much better than linking to some filtered list.

Comment: Cant edit a comment after some time...weird...
anyway - they are listing templates that aren't even ready yet...way to confuse us and waste our time. Yes we know it is a beta, but even an alpha software would not list unavailable stuff..."The complex list starter hasn't been done yet unfortunately. Still a work in progress!
" check out https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3939

Comment: Yeah you're right. I just tried `complex-list` with `2.0.0-beta.32` and now it even crashes `Error with start Error: No starter template named "complex-list"`  Either they should leave it out or add a comment `not available yet`.

Comment: I noticed`complex` template is removed in 3.7.0

Answer (score 15):

**!CURRENTLY** (will most likely change) you can do the following :
The `--ts` is optional if you want it in typescript.

```
ionic start tempName blank --v2 --ts

ionic start tempName tabs --v2 --ts

ionic start tempName base --v2 --ts

ionic start tempName sidemenu --v2 --ts
```

**UPDATE**. you do not need to specify `--ts` anymore. It is default now

```
ionic start tempName blank --v2
```

**UPDATE** I found the full list, please note that some have not been updated in a while

**1**.A starter application with Ionic Deploy functionality to enable live updates of your app in the app store.

```
ionic start myApp deploy
```

**2**.A starter template for the Ionic Framework. Your basic batteries-included Ionic starter app, plus analytics.

```
ionic start myApp analytics
```

**3**.Starter pack for building Ionic apps on top of the Salesforce platform created as a partnership between Ionic and Salesforce.

```
 ionic start myApp salesforce
```

**4**.An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side menu

```
ionic start myApp maps
```

**5**.A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navigation in the content area

```
ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

**6**.A blank starter project for Ionic

```
ionic start myApp blank --v2
```

**7**.Use Ionic, Three.js and WebGL to build a Google Cardboard app as part of the Angular Cardboard Hackathon.

```
ionic start myApp cardboard
```

**8**.A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface

```
ionic start myTabs tabs --v2
```

**9**.This tutorial goes along with the example on Ionic v2 documentation

```
ionic start myTutorial tutorial --v2
```

**10**.An ionic starter project containing the ionic.io services.

```
ionic start myApp io
```

Answer (score 12):

For **ionic 2** this is the only command to know templates --

```
ionic start --list
```

See my local System Setup-

---

```
D:\appsDir>ionic info

Your system information:

 ordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.13
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installe
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8
Node Version: v7.2.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

And this will generate following out put -

```
D:\AppsDir>ionic start --list

Downloading Starter Templates - http://code.ionicframework.com/content/starter-t
emplates.json
Ionic Starter templates


blank ................ A blank starter project for Ionic
complex-list ......... A complex list starter template
maps ................. An Ionic starter project using Google Maps and a side men
u
salesforce ........... A starter project for Ionic and Salesforce
sidemenu ............. A starting project for Ionic using a side menu with navig
ation in the content area
tabs ................. A starting project for Ionic using a simple tabbed interface
```

Along with this all we have some more template as-

```
$ ionic start appName tutorial --v2
```

***Note:- Don't use $ for windows OS.***

Hope it will help you ...

Answer (score 5):

You can use CLI commend: ionic templates or ionic start -l to see all the available templates "installed" on your dev machine.

Comment: `ionic templates` doesn't appear to be a valid command. `ionic start -l` does list the templates.

Answer (score 5):

You can create ionic 2 project with side menu template using following cli command:

```
ionic start your_project_name  --v2 sidemenu
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems `--list` is removed from command prompt in Ionic2,

just type `ionic start` in command prompt and new Gui asks for name, directory and template and it will create your app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `ionic start --list` for ionic 2 templates.

Answer (score 0):

I simple use `ionic start` it give me instructions with all the available templates, I just select which template I want to start my project with. I think that is best.